# Can wrapping System.in in a BufferedInputStream improve performance on some JDK's?

Tags: java

When reading from Standard Input using System.in can wrapping it with a BufferedInputStream improve performance or is it already buffered already?

An example when used in combination with a Scanner

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
//or
Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
```

The [System.in javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) does not explicitly state whether it is buffered or not.

Looking at the source code of my x64 Linux 1.8.0_111 java.lang.System#initializeSystemClass suggests it is buffered.

```
 FileInputStream fdIn = new FileInputStream(FileDescriptor.in);
 ...
 setIn0(new BufferedInputStream(fdIn));
```

Is there any platform/jdk implementation where System.in is unbuffered and it makes sense to wrap it?

Comment: It all depends. How fast can you type?

Answer (score 1):

Well a quick bit of debug:

```
System.out.println(System.in.getClass());
```

> class java.io.BufferedInputStream

So no, wrapping `System#in` wouldn't help, as it is already a `BufferedInputStream`. This may be OS-dependent, as I haven't found an actual JLS/etc specification for what the InputStream for `System#in` will always be.

Answer (score 1):

Will it hurt? Most likely not.

Will it help? Depends, but probably not.

Keep in mind that the operating system has a say here too. One should never forget that the JVM is just one layer in a whole stack of components. In other words : your Linux kernel might be doing all kinds of things behind the covers - so it really doesn't matter that much what your application code does here.